# How can I find the installation directory of a Java application?

Tags: java, path, installation, directory, classpath

I need to find the installation directory of a Java application. I will use it to find recourses that are not on the classpath. What is the best solution for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will give you the location of class file in System from where it is being executing.

```
this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```